# problema con un <input/> en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy aprendiendo Angular siguiendo un curso. Estoy usando VSCode con angular 13.1.4.
Para no agregar un formulario completo porque este pedazo de código será usado solo en esta porción del programa, el tutor propone hacer el siguiente código:

```
<input
      type="text"
      (keyup.enter)="buscarProducto( #txtBuscar.value )"
      placeholder="Buscar"
      id="urku-search"
      #txtBuscar
      class="rk-search-field"
    />
```

tengo declarado mi modulo en el componente ts de la siguiente manera:

```
buscarProducto(termino: string) {
    console.log(termino);
  }
```

Me da un error:

> any
> Property 'searchProduct' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
> header.component.ts(5, 2): Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
> Parser Error: Private identifiers are not supported. Unexpected private identifier: #txtSearch at column 16 in [searchProduct( #txtSearch.value )] in /home/luca/Documentos/Programacion/curso_angular/src/app/shared/header/header.component.html@58:25ngtsc(-995002)
> header.component.ts(5, 2): Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.

Perdón, pero no me muestra todos los errores en español.

Alguna ayuda para solucionar el problema? Puede ser una actualización de angular que haga las cosas diferente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas, te comento rápido puesto que es un error tonto, no puedes usar `#` para llamar a esa etiqueta porque es privado, para llegar a la etiqueta tienes que usar la palabra reservada `this` y luego el nombre del `input`

```
<input
  type="text"
  (keyup.enter)="buscarProducto( this.txtBuscar.value)"
  placeholder="Buscar"
  id="urku-search"
  #txtBuscar
  class="rk-search-field"
/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy recién aprendiendo y hay muchas cosas que me superan. Lo solucione incluso sin el "this.".